# How to make players gliding with Elytra glow

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I am looking for a command that makes players glow once they're gliding with the elytra. I read that players gliding with the Elytra get a FallFlying tag, but I don't know how to pull it of exactly.
I've tried `/execute as @a[nbt={tag=FallFlying}] run effect give @s minecraft:glowing 1` but this does sadly not work.
What is the right command for this?

Answer (score 1):

It's `FallFlying:true`, not `tag=FallFlying`. You can check things like this by running `/data get entity @s`.

Comment: ... and sole NBT is specified with a colon rather than an equals sign.

Comment: @pppery Thanks for the correction. Did you intend to continue from another comment? I only see one. I'm not sure if I said that already, but you can just edit my posts directly.

Comment: No, I didn't, it was only one comment, and yes, you have told me I can edit already.